# Is there a better way in Linux to query a memory mapping than text parsing /proc/self/maps?

Tags: linux, virtual-memory

In Linux/Android, is there a way to get information about a virtual address in the current process--such as the base address of the mapping--without writing a complicated text parser to understand `/proc/self/maps`?  (Which also takes O(n) time.)

Essentially, an equivalent of Windows `VirtualQuery` and macOS/iOS `mach_vm_region_info_64`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding mapped memory from inside a process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53022573/finding-mapped-memory-from-inside-a-process) And see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8069892/530160), assuming the thing you want to identify is a shared library.